# MongoDB, how to insert object into new collection?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, pdo

I have a return object coming from instagram.
I am trying to skate the entire build DB table structure process, I understand Mongo is the ideal DB to use for this task.

I am using the regular instagram libraries  https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
and my test code runs without error.
I don have the PhP PECL mongo libraries installed, I should be good to go.

```
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;
$instagram = new Instagram(array(
  'apiKey'      => 'xxx',
  'apiSecret'   => 'xxx',
  'apiCallback' => 'http://103.238.173.97/success.php'
  ));

$accessToken = $instagram->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'] = $accessToken;
$instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken']);
$popular = $instagram->getPopularMedia();
// After getting the response, let's iterate the payload
var_dump($popular);
```

added just now:

```
$conn = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost/?w=1');

$db = $conn->instagram;

// access collection
$collection = $db->instagram1;
$collection->insert($popular);
```

How would I construct a PDO query to 'autobuild' the table structure just like the JSON object at reply from my request?

[instagram JSON object](https://pastee.org/hpwa4)

[Repaste of object. Most got cut off due to size](http://paste.ee/p/QLifA)

Update:
I tried to insert straight into a collection, I get no error but the DB is still the same size

> show dbs
>   Data       0.078GB
>   admin      (empty)
>   instagram  0.078GB
>   local      0.078GB
>   test       0.078GB
>   week1      (empty)

Comment: @Daan I don't know why you edited the most important keywords in the text. The entire purpose of this question is to address 'big data' issues.

Comment: You exaggerate a little because the object is not that big.

Comment: @Daan because it's so big, all of the pastie site chop it or crash. I found one that would hold it.  Yes, it is 'that' big.

Comment: That's bigger indeed, nevertheless those words don't make your question better.

Comment: You don't use PDO with MongoDB. Also this question seems very basic if you just read the documentation an inch, for starters if you read the documentation on the PHP driver you would know that PDO has nothing to do with MongoDB.

Comment: @Sammaye I am not working with the cli at all. I am working from within PHP exclusively and PDO is the preferred database access method.

Comment: that explains the lack of documentation   o.0

Comment: When did I ever say you was working with the CLI? I am unsure what part of my comment referred to the CLI in any manner what so ever. Instagram may say that the preferred method is via a PDO enabled driver to a compatible database but MongoDB is not PDO compliant nor has a PDO driver, it simply cannot, and nor does it need one